# How do I connect Romex to under cabinet LED strip lights?

Tags: lighting

I have 14-2 romex running out of five different holes under my cabinets, All connecting back to a single switch. The idea is to have hardwired undercabinet led lights. Planning ahead, just got the drywall up, How will I connect the Romex to the strip lights? Will there be five giant transformers/jboxes under the cabinets for each spot? Is 12” of Romex sticking out enough? Trying to visualize what the install will look like

Comment: What make and model are the LED undercabinet fixtures you're looking at?

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Philips-Hue-White-and-Color-Ambiance-Dimmable-LED-Light-Strip-Plus-Smart-Wireless-Light-Base-Kit-80-555334/313025879

Comment: I don't think those can be hard wired in.    It has a transformer that needs to be plugged into a normal plug....ie wire behind wall into an appropriate box with plug mounted in it.

Comment: Post a picture showing where the holes are (are they in the wall beneath the cabinets?), and also showing the underside of the cabinets and any valance or trim they have along their bottom.  This is leading towards whether you could attractively install outlets under the cabinets (or perhaps in them) to plug in those lights.

Comment: I don't have the cabinets yet. I just have 14/2 Romex coming out of the drywall at exactly 36" mark, where the bottom of the cabinet will be. I don't want to install outlets, is there another kind of LED strip lighting I can install via hardwire to the 14/2 Romex?

Comment: add some outlets in a hidden location. you don't want to hard-wire LEDs as that makes them a major pain to replace and vastly limits product selection.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I will revert to bar lights then, since it looks much easier to hardwire